# Launching a program via JNLP produces security exception

Tags: javafx-2

If I read the JavaFX deployment guide correctly, I should be able to deploy an unsigned application so long as "the application requires [no] elevated privileges... ." I have reduced my application to the following bit of code:

```
package fxadhoc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXAdHoc
    extends Application
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println( "launch" );
        launch( args );
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Pane    root    = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add( new Label( "Testing" ) );
        Scene   scene  = new Scene( root );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

When I double-click the jar file (created by NetBeans) nothing happens. When I try to launch via the html or jnlp files (also created by NetBeans) I get a security exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.debug" "read")
```

The full stack trace is provided below.

I am running Windows 7 with all the latest updates applied. I have downloaded the most recent version of NetBeans (7.1.1) which comes equipped with the latest version of JavaFX. I have downloaded the JavaFX samples, and they run fine. (In case you're curious, I tried self-signing the application and got the exception "ava.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\jack\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXAdHoc\dist\bin\mat.dll"). I get the same exceptions when I build on Linux (again using NetBeans 7.1.1).

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks...

The full stack trace for the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application launch error
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:97)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.debug" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.runtime.SystemProperties.getProperty(SystemProperties.java:178)
    at com.sun.javafx.runtime.SystemProperties$1.run(SystemProperties.java:67)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.runtime.SystemProperties.<clinit>(SystemProperties.java:62)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Try a later [JavaFX developer preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) and mention the version and build number you tried.  Try running the [Getting Started NetBeans Project](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/get_started/ColorfulCircles.zip) as a jnlp and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had three different problems; please correct me if I get any of this wrong.

1. It *should* be possible to deploy an unsigned jar file, but you can't. I believe this is a known issue.
2. Downloading and installing the JavaFX runtime doesn't automatically make it available from the path. (I don't know why I can run the samples when I can't run my own code, but I'll have to figure that out.) Putting `"...\JavaFX 2.o runtime\bin"` in my path cured my "mat.dll not found" problem. Presumably getting the directory containing libmat.so into the path on my Linux system will cure the problem there, too.
3. As I tried different approaches to fixing the problem, I was also occasionally getting an "unsigned resource" exception, even when my jar file was signed. I believe this is a known Java issue going back to at least 1.4. The solution was to **disable** caching temporary files (`Windows control panel/java/general/settings`). Note that some remarks I read said that **enabling** caching is what fixes the problem.

Comment: 1. to run as a web start application, you have to sign it. you can use Netbean 7.1 or build it by hand using ant-javafx-tool provided in javafx runtime library.